# Any efficient solution possible without using graphs?

Tags: algorithm, stack

A list of tuples `(i,j)` is given, each tuple `(i,j)` tells you that `i` and `j` are friends. Friendship is contagious, so if `i` and `j` are friends, and `j` and `k` are friends, `i` and `k` are friends, even if the tuple `(i,k)` is not present. So the question is, for a set of integers 1 to N, and a list of tuples, how to efficiently determine whether all numbers are friends among each other.

Barring the naive algo, is it possible to devise an efficient algo to do this without using graphs?

There is another variant of this question, where the question is to find whether a given tuple `(m,n)` are friends. This can be implemented using a stack.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question. Are you looking for an implementation or a certain algorithmic complexity ( big O notation)?

Comment: This sounds like a job for [Disjoint Sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), but there could be a more efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I've learned an algorithm for making mazes by removing walls that is quite applicable.

```
int friendGroups[N];

// initially, all numbers are in a "forever alone" group.
for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    friendGroups[i] = i;
}

int findFriendGroup(int p) {
    int g = friendGroups[p];
    if (g != p) {
        g = friendGroups[p] = findFriendGroup(g);
    }
    return g;
}
void addFriendship(int i, int j) {
    friendGroup[findFriendGroup(i)] = findFriendGroup(j);
}
int areFriends(int i, int j) {
    return (findFriendGroup(i) == findFriendGroup(j));
}
```

`findFriendGroup()` looks potentially inefficient, but each call asymptotically costs O(A^(-1)(N)) where A^(-1) is the inverse Ackermann function, which is so close to O(1) it's not worth worrying about.

```
int singleFriendGroup() {
    int g = findFriendGroup(0);
    int i;

    for(i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        if (findFriendGroup(i) != g) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Each person "points" to another or himself.  Each friend group has a primary member who points at himself (`friendGroups[i] == i`).  `findFriendGroup()` follows the chain of points to find the primary member of a group, and on the way back makes each person in the chain point directly at the primary member.  To unify two groups (`addFriendship()`), make the primary member of one group point at the primary member of another group.

Comment: this is exactly a Disjoint Sets implementation

Comment: So ultimately, in order to find out whether all are friends or not, I will have to call `areFriends` `nC2` times, right?

Comment: By the way, please explain your algorithm!

Comment: I added a O(n) function `singleFriendGroup()` and some explanation.